# R: Different values of multiple lines on Y-axis in one graph

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, yaxis

Some time ago i have performed a graph, which contained multiple lines with different set of values. The result was this image with values on y-axis as sections od values:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRwhz.jpg
After a while i used the exact same code, but just slightly changed some values in the table, and the output is this image with continuous y-axis: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgYnn.jpg

In both cases I used exactly the same code, but i got different output twice. I would like to get the first output where y-axis is shown in sections in order to better display the deviation of values through years. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?
The data I am using is the *.csv table which has 6 columns with the values which represent the percentage of land use in my study area

```
Sensor    Acquisition_time  Land   Sea   Lagoon River
Landsat_4 1992              72.79  19.05 7.56   0.60
Landsat_5 1984              72.96  19.17 7.02   0.85
Landsat_5 1988              72.82  19.41 7.09   0.68
Landsat_5 1996              73.46  19.27 6.71   0.56
Landsat_5 2000              72.72  19.23 7.43   0.62
Landsat_5 2004              72.48  19.05 7.78   0.69
Landsat_5 2008              72.67  19.14 7.49   0.70
Landsat_8 2013              72.66  19.10 7.49   0.75
Landsat_8 2016              72.81  19.03 7.38   0.78
```

And the code i used is:

```
table <- read.csv("results.csv", header=TRUE)
mtbl <- melt(table, id.vars="Acquisition_time", measure.vars = c("Land", "Sea", "Lagoon", "River"))

#draw a graph
ggplot(data=mtbl, aes(x= Acquisition_time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Years", breaks = mtbl$Acquisition_time)
```

What should i add to get discrete values on y-axis i obtained automatically before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your value, being a factor in the first example, and a continuous value in the second example. Here is a reproducible example:

```
Acquisition_time <- c(1992,1984,1988,1996,2000,2004,2008,2013,2016)
Land <- c(72.79,72.96,72.82,73.46,72.72,72.48,72.67,72.66,72.81)
Sea <- c(19.05,19.17,19.41,19.27,19.23,19.05,19.14,19.10,19.03)
Lagoon <- c(7.56,7.02,7.09,6.71,7.43,7.78,7.49,7.49,7.38)
River <- c(0.60,0.85,0.68,0.56,0.62,0.69,0.70,0.75,0.78)

table <- data.frame(Acquisition_time, Land, Sea, Lagoon, River)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtbl <- table %>% gather(variable, value, -Acquisition_time)

mtblfac <- mtbl %>% mutate(value = factor(value))

# with value as numeric
ggplot(data=mtbl, aes(x= Acquisition_time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Years")

# with value as factor
ggplot(data=mtblfac, aes(x= Acquisition_time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Years")
```

But I would advice you to use facets and a continuous value like the following example, since you preserve the relation between the values, without making them categorical. But with the `scales="free"` option, you are able to distinguish the differences, just as well as your first example.

```
# with value as numeric and facets
ggplot(data=mtbl, aes(x= Acquisition_time, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Years") +
  facet_grid(variable~., scales="free")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback and detailed description. I was not aware of the possibility to use facets, it works perfectly now!